# Path Varaible error after call the controller with path variable and then other controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, path-variables

I have problem in using pathvariable in spring mvc application.

I have two controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(@RequestMapping(value = { "BuyPackage/{company_code}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String controller1(@PathVariable("company_code")int company_code){
............
}


@RequestMapping(@RequestMapping(value = { "Preview" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String controller2(){
............
}
```

when the first controller called the url is `localhost:8080/myapp/BuyPackage/1`

and then when the second controller called the url turn to `localhost:8080/myapp/BuyPackage/Preview` and the error occur.

the url should be like this :`localhost:8080/myapp/Preview`

Can anyone help me to deal with this problem.?

Comment: Why are you using twice `@RequestMapping`??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jstl](https://jstl.java.net/).  Try to use this with your link  `<c:url value='/Preview' />`

Example: `<a href="<c:url value='/Preview' />">Link to Preview</a>`

Comment: the /Preiview handle the POST method that submit from form Like <form:form action="Preview" method="post">.......</form:form> how can i use c:url in it???

Comment: you can use <form:form action="<c:url value='/Preview' />" method="post">.......</form:form>. I think you should use <c:url...> every time you need to redirect to some page.
Try to do this, you have 1 link on you navigation bar <a href="/somepage">...</a>. multi click on that link, in some case your url in browser will be /somepage/somepage/somepage -> 404 error!!. so use <c:url> if you need